# Node.js spawn and `*` for selecting multiple files

Tags: bash, node.js

If I create a `test` dir and put `foo.js` in it, then I can run

```
node test/*
```

just fine to run all the files in the directory. But if create a js file in the parent directory and have it do

```
spawn('node', ['test/*']);
```

then it gives me stderr output

> Error: Cannot find module '/mypath/test/*'

I've come to realize that this is because `*` is a convenience provided by the shell (right?). So, my questions are:

1. Is there any way to do my desired `spawn` without using `fs` to read in the contents of the `test` directory?
2. How exactly does the shell translate `test/*`, and is it possible to tap into this awesome power from my apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The humble `exec` function, described in the API docs as a mere higher-level abstraction for spawning child processes, *does* give the desired results:

```
require('child_process').exec('node test/*');
```

works fine. It seems that `spawn` escapes its arguments and `exec` doesn't.

Comment: Accepting this as "the answer" for now, but really looking for a more thorough explanation of how `spawn` and `exec` treat globs differently.

Answer (score 2):

The * functionality (along with ?, {}, etc.) are provided by [Glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Luckily someone has made Node.JS bindings for glob - [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

Install it with `npm install glob` and then use it like this (untested):

```
var glob = require('glob');
glob('test/*', null, function (err, matches) {
    matches.forEach(function (match) {
        spawn('node', match);
    });
})
```

Comment: And by "someone," you mean Isaac Schlueter, the creator of npm. :) Thanks for the pointer!